# Max or min of $F(x) = \int_0^{2x-x^2} \cos\Big(\frac {1}{1+t^2}\Big) \,dt$

Tags: integration, analysis, derivatives

$$F(x) = \int_0^{2x-x^2} \cos\left(\frac {1}{1+t^2}\right) \,dt$$

Does the function have a max or min?

Can someone help me with this? How can I calculate the maximum and minimum?

Comment: Have you got, in your book or your lecture notes, anything called "The fundamental theorem of calculus"?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Let: $$I(x) = \int_0^x \cos\left(\frac{1}{1+t^2}\right)\, {\rm d}t \quad \text{and} \quad g(x) = 2x-x^2.$$ This way, $F = I \circ g$ and you get $F'(x) = I'(g(x)) \, g'(x)$ by the [chain rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule). To compute $I'$ use the [fundamental theorem of calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus). Look for points where $F'(x) = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Using the [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/integral-calculus/indefinite-definite-integrals/fundamental-theorem-of-calculus/v/fundamental-theorem-of-calculus) and the [Chain Rule](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XIQ-KnsAsbg) you may show that

$$\frac{d}{dx}\Bigg(\int_{f_1(x)}^{f_2(x)}g(t) dt\Bigg) = g(f_2(x))f_2'(x) - g(f_1(x))f'_1(x)$$

Then take $g(t) = \cos\Big(\frac{1}{1 + t^2}\Big)$, $f_1(x) = 0$ and $f_2(x) = 2x - x^2$ to get

$$F'(x) = \cos \Bigg(\frac{1}{1 + (2x - x^2)}\Bigg)(2 - 2x) - (\cos 1)0$$

And now try to find $F'(x) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Function $\cos(1/(t^2+1))$ is increasing and positive than we check min and max 
of $2x-x^2=x(2-x)$.
Min of integer is in $x=2$ and $x=0$ and it's value is $F=0$.
Max is in max of function $2x-x^2\geq 0$ with and that is in $x=1$ and value is $x=1$.